# How to change application theme by choosing option from a listview or spinner in android?

Tags: java, android, themes, android-theme, android-styles

On every item click, the mentioned them should be applied to the application.

But when I run the app in my phone and select one option, the theme doesn't change and also the toast doesn't shows up.

No error is showing up and also app is not crashing. It's just not working.

And I'm willing to do this by a spinner. What should I do ?

Here is my code :

```
final ListView themeList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.themeList);

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    if (position == 0) {
        getApplicaiton().setTheme(R.style.themeOne);
    } else if (position == 1) {
        getApplicaiton().setTheme(R.style.themeTwo);
    } else if (position == 2) {
        getApplicaiton().setTheme(R.style.themeThree);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(ThemeActivity.this, "Something went wrong, please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Comment: Follow this tutorial http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html

Comment: If you change a theme, you  have to restart the Activity to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

According to Android website documentation for setTheme

> Set the base theme for this context. Note that this should be called before any views are instantiated in the Context (for example before calling setContentView(View) or inflate(int, ViewGroup)).

So you need to make changes before that.

Answer (score 0):

The `setTheme` - method has to be called before you create any view.
So to really "change" your theme, you would have to recreate your activity and call `setTheme` before you call `setContentView` (or maybe even before sou call `super.onCreate`.

Another solution would be to not change the theme, but the elements itself (like the acitonbar, notificationbar etc.) dynamically. Almost every attribute which can be set as a theme can be set in your java code too.